# How to compare two large Delphi units where order of definitions/implementations is all different?

Tags: delphi, comparison, compare

I have two Delphi units generated from the same WSDL import, one by XE2 and one by XE3.
I want to check if there are any significant differences, but the order of the definitions/implementations are all different in the two files.
No way I'm going to be able to edit these 25000+ line files to match up....

Does anyone have a smart idea how I could do my compare?
It could well be that the files are completely identical, but I'm interested in any tiny differences...

Example parts of XE2 file:

```
FreeBusyResponseType = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[GblCplx] }
GetUserAvailabilityResponseType = class;      { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
SetUserOofSettingsResponse2 = class;          { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
FieldURIOrConstantType = class;               { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"[GblCplx] }
MessageXml           = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Cplx] }
BaseRequestType      = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[GblCplx] }
GetFolderType        = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
BaseMoveCopyItemType = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[GblCplx] }
CopyItemType         = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
MoveItemType         = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
CreateAttachmentType = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
BaseMoveCopyFolderType = class;               { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[GblCplx] }
MoveFolderType       = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
CopyFolderType       = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
GetItemType          = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
SetUserOofSettingsRequest2 = class;           { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
GetUserOofSettingsRequest2 = class;           { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
BaseDelegateType     = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[GblCplx] }
GetRoomListsType     = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
GetRoomsType         = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }

[snip]

implementation
  uses SysUtils;

destructor FreeBusyResponseType.Destroy;
begin
  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FResponseMessage);
  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FFreeBusyView);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure FreeBusyResponseType.SetResponseMessage(Index: Integer; const AResponseMessageType: ResponseMessageType);
begin
  FResponseMessage := AResponseMessageType;
  FResponseMessage_Specified := True;
end;
```

Example parts of XE3 file:

```
GetUserAvailabilityResponseType = class;      { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
FreeBusyResponseType = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[GblCplx] }
FieldURIOrConstantType = class;               { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"[GblCplx] }
SetUserOofSettingsResponse2 = class;          { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
MessageXml           = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Cplx] }
BaseRequestType      = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[GblCplx] }
BaseMoveCopyFolderType = class;               { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[GblCplx] }
MoveFolderType       = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
CopyFolderType       = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
CreateAttachmentType = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
GetItemType          = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
BaseMoveCopyItemType = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[GblCplx] }
MoveItemType         = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
CopyItemType         = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
GetRoomsType         = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
SetUserOofSettingsRequest2 = class;           { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
BaseDelegateType     = class;                 { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[GblCplx] }
DeleteUserConfigurationType = class;          { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
CreateUserConfigurationType = class;          { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }
UpdateUserConfigurationType = class;          { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"[Lit][GblCplx] }

[snip]

implementation
  uses SysUtils;

constructor GetUserAvailabilityResponseType.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FSerializationOptions := [xoLiteralParam];
end;

destructor GetUserAvailabilityResponseType.Destroy;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to System.Length(FFreeBusyResponseArray)-1 do
    SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FFreeBusyResponseArray[I]);
  System.SetLength(FFreeBusyResponseArray, 0);
  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FSuggestionsResponse);
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Comment: put the files in svn an do a diff?

Comment: What problems are you having with these units? Why do you trust the XE2 one? Because you've been using it without problem? If so, and it does what you need, then carry on using it.

Comment: Sometimes, it works to sort both files (creating a completely invalid source file), compare the sorted files, and for each difference, search where it comes from in the unsorted files. But it's not a general answer; I can't guess whether it will be enough for your needs.

Comment: @HVD Of course, why didn't I think of that? That works for detecting tiny differences. It turns out the files are identical. Thanks!

Comment: @David The XE2 file does not work, I want to check if XE3 does better. *One* part of that is to see if the units generated from the WDSL differ from XE2 to XE3. They don't.

Comment: What does Subversion add to the process, @Whosrdaddy? Why not just do a diff on the files directly?

Comment: @RobKennedy offcourse you are right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ModelMaker](http://www.modelmakertools.com/) has a compare tool on class/method implementation level. It is not affected by the order of them in the source file.

Comment: Although HVD's comment helped me out already, your suggestion works too. ModelMaker has a fully functional 45-day trial, so this is a good solution for an occasional compare.